# jQuery datepicker hover output date

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery

I am using jQuery datepicker and I want to display out the date that the user is currently hovering over. I have the code below (you can also try the code with JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $(".ui-state-default").live("mouseenter", function() {
        $("h1").text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

​
Currently when hovering over a date, the number of the date (ie. 23) is outputed to the h1 tags. I want to change this so that it outputs the whole date and stores it in a variable.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the best way I did it, because I found nothing in the jQuery UI Datepicker documentation for getting the actual Date, but here you go:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $("h1").text($(this).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-month",$(this).parents()).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-year",$(this).parents()).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/1/

The second version with saving the actual Date + alerting it afterwards:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $("h1").text($(this).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-month",$(this).parents()).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-year",$(this).parents()).text());
    var actualDate=$('h1').text();
        alert(actualDate);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/2/

UPDATE: I previously had .live as an event handler but .live is no deprecated and .on() is the method to go.

Comment: This is very handy, works great--just wanted to note that jQuery says "live" is deprecated and to use "on" now to attach an event handler: http://api.jquery.com/on/