# how to highlight a date & add message to that date when i drag the mouse on it in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the java script code.But i want to add some thing more.
I would like to highlight a date & add message to that date when I drag the mouse on it.
the code is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>DatePicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script src="Js/JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Js/JScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
 <script>
   $(function () {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
   //       $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -60, maxDate:0 });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div style="height: 220px">
   <div style="height: 191px; width: 1156px">
    <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want it should display a message on the date. Ex:- We declared that 15th july is a holiday.When I hover the mouse on the 15th in the calender,a small message will display(ex:-today is holiday)when I remove the mouse the message will dis appear.

Comment: What do you mean "when I drag the mouse on it"?  It's very simple to add code that executes when the datepicker is closed, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean when i drag the mouse on a date in the calender & if,that date is a holiday (If we declared in the program)then it should display a small message.

Comment: have a look at this. I think this is you want.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838729/jquery-datepicker-hover-output-date

Comment: Thank you Rahul Kumar Pandey for the nice answer.But,it shows the date.I want it should display a message on the date. Ex:- We declared that 15th july is a holiday.When I hover the mouse on the 15th in the calender,a small message will display(ex:-today is holiday)when I remove the mouse the message will dis appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event of the element you want to drag your cursor on. In the handler you can change the style of other elements, as you need.