# jQuery datepicker hover date output

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get the date hovered over in the jQuery datepicker ui.  I've had no luck with the other solutions posted on this forum.

Here is a link to some code I am trying to get working:

[jQuery datepicker hover output date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838729/jquery-datepicker-hover-output-date)

The below does not work for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<style></style>
<body>


<h1>This should change on hover</h1>

<div class="demo">
    <input type="text" id="date1">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


$(function() {
    $("#date1").datepicker();
    $(".ui-state-default").live("mouseenter", function() {
        $("h1").text($(this).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-month",$(this).parents()).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-year",$(this).parents()).text());
        var actualDate=$('h1').text();
        alert(actualDate);
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using a version of jQuery that still supports `live()`? It was deprecated quite a long time ago. Would throw console errors if it isn't supported

Comment: my jQuery version is current. Would I have to change it to the ".on()" method? How could this be done?

Comment: yes, and chose an initial selector that exists like `$(document)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This provides the day, month, year when hovering over the dates

Reference for the date & years:
http://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/get-date-mouseover-cell-jquery-ui-datepicker

The link to the datepicker element hierarchy was useful: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover', function(e){

    var c1 =        $(this).closest('.ui-datepicker-group');    //closest datepicker...

    var day1 =      $(this).text();
    var month1 =    c1.find('.ui-datepicker-month').text();
    var year1 =     c1.find('.ui-datepicker-year').text();

    var fullDate = day1 + "_" + month1 + "_" + year1;
    $('h1').html(fullDate);
});
```